# WCF Security with Custom Basic Authentification

Tags: wcf, security, rest, ssl, basic-authentication

I've setup security in my **RESTFUL** WCF services using Custom Basic Authentification (thus desactivating the iis Basic Authentification and not using Windows Accounts Login at all; my service is hosted by iis) using the following link.

[blog link](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.fr/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html)

I understand the consumers have to implement a client to pass credentials in the request header.

It is 64bits based encoded and we can see credentials passing in firebug network tab while debugging (it is always the same string encoded <=> same credential .......)

So, in addition, to enforce security I will add SSL to encrypt the url :

https://myrestfulserviceurl.com/Method

Now the consumers ask me why we don't just put the login and password in the url request i.e

https: // myrestfulserviceurl.com/Method?login=XXX&password=YYY
(also combined with SSL)

Thus the change requires to add login and password as parameters in my Operation Contract and call a method for authentification in my method "Method".. etc etc

My question is :

What is the difference (both scenarii will use ssl) between **Custom Basic Authentification** (credentials in request header) & simply **passing credentials in url in param** ?

I mean : I'm just asking myself why I do bother to implement Basic Authentification. Passing credentials in url or in header look similar : it's passing stuff in the request. But talking in term of security, it looks the same ?

Basic Authentification looks not more secure excepted the 64bits based encoding.

Correct me if i'm wrong.

I am just looking a reason why implementing Custom Basic Authentification.

Any idea/advise?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The main difference that comes to mind is to do with how visible the data is and how long it is likely to be retained.

For instance, assuming SSL is terminated at your application server, values in the get parameters are likely to be automatically logged to your file system (in request logs for instance).  Having usernames and passwords in there is not ideal as it makes it much easier for them to be leaked.

If SSL is terminated at a loadbalancer or some similar proxy, then the usernames and passwords could be saved in request logs on servers you may not be thinking about and probably have less control over.

By contrast, the Authentication header is much less likely to be logged to places you're not expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I thought about doind this myself and decided against it because i wanted the Restful URL's to focus only on the operations and keep security out of it, for example I might want to re-use the same code on a different application.

Also Im not sure but i think there could be a security implication concerning replay attacks, if someone obtained the link then they could execute it in any http client. If you used the authroisation attribute in the http header you could avoid this by putting an expiration on it. Also i think its better to hide this information from the html page body.

The dude who wrote this http://lbadri.wordpress.com/2012/07/30/anatomy-of-a-simple-web-token-swt/, which is taken from his book "Pro ASP.NET web Security". Gives a pretty decent example of creating a token which you could then use in the http header "Authorisation", like: **Authorization: Basic d2FsaWRAGssSGZ21haWwuY29tOn236dhbGlk**